# Failure to open Spyder after crashing

Tags: python, spyder

Spyder unexpectedly froze and I turned off my PC (as in, pulled out the power cord). Now I cannot open Spyder, and I get this error when try to do so:

[image: screenshot]

There is no documentation online for this, and I don't understand what it means. Please help.

Comment: A workaround for a similar problem is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1325), does that fix it for you?

Comment: No still the same problem. I'll try to reinstall it...

Comment: There's a pid file somewhere which is corrupted. Remove that file and it should be fine. If you don't know where the file is, have a look at the `lockfile.py` implementation and for example print the filename before line 174.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. Run the 'Reset Spyder settings' program and restart your PC
2. Do a clean reinstall of Spyder

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the .spyder directory from your home directory. If you run spyder with Python 3, this would be the .spyder-py3 directory. 
(The spyder user settings directory is probably corrupted)